# How do you comment your db schema objects in SQL Azure database project?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, coding-style, azure-sql-database

As far as I understand `sp_addextendedproperty` is not available in SQL Azure databases as of now. So.. How do you comment your tables, columns, sprocs and other objects in your database project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a database table declaration with comments:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone encountering this now, as at April 2018, `sp_addextendedproperty` **is** (now) available and works (at least for attaching descriptions to columns!)